# How to run a Netlify function in Svelte

Tags: serverless, svelte, netlify, netlify-function

**Problem description**

I would like to run a [Netlify function](https://www.netlify.com/products/functions/) in a [Svelte app](https://svelte.dev/). However, during development, the requests for the function cannot be found (404). I assume this has to do with the port on which Netlify is serving the functions.

The issue only arises in development. When the app is deployed on Netlify, the function call works just fine. And it also works fine without Svelte.

I have used the basic [Svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template). My Netflify function is called "number" and just returns "42".

**number.js:**

```
const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(42),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return { statusCode: 500, body: error.toString() };
    }
};

module.exports = { handler };
```

When I run `netlify dev`, this starts Netlify's development server with Svelte. It logs:

```
 Loaded function number (​http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/number​).
◈ Functions server is listening on 52041
```

But `http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/number` does give a 404. Only `http://localhost:52041/.netlify/functions/number` works here. Can someone explain the first log then, isn't this just incorrect?

The problem now is that the functions port changes every time I call `netlify dev`. We can fix this by changing the Netlify configuration file:

**netlify.toml:**

```
[build]
    publish = "public/"
    functions = "functions/"

[dev]
    publish = "public/"
    functions = "functions/"
    port = 8080
    functionsPort = 52041
```

In the end, I would like to add a button to my Svelte app which makes a fetch request to that function.

**App.svelte:**

```
<script>
    async function getNumber() {
        const url = `http://localhost:52041/.netlify/functions/number`;
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const data = await res.json();
        window.alert(data);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={getNumber}>Click me</button>
```

This works now in development, but not in production: Here the url should be `/.netlify/functions/number`.

So my question is:

- How can we determine the correct URL which works in each case (dev/prod)?
- Is there a more elegant way to call a Netlify function in a Svelte app?
- In particular, is it possible to use the URL `/.netlify/functions/number` somehow in both cases (dev/prod)?

Related questions on the internet:

- https://answers.netlify.com/t/netlify-dev-changes-proxy-port-eveytime-it-runs
- https://answers.netlify.com/t/netlify-dev-functions-gatsby-ports-etc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `netlify.toml`, under `[dev]`, put `targetPort = 8080` *instead of* `port = 8080`.

When running `ntl dev`, Netlify tries to autodetect the framework that is being used and offers up some default configuration options. In December 2021 there was a breaking change with the release of [sirv 2.0.0](https://github.com/lukeed/sirv/releases/tag/v2.0.0)—which is used to serve up the Svelte app—that changed the default port *from* 5000 *to* 8080. Netlify has not been updated to account for this, and so without additional configuration it is still expecting the Svelte app to exist on port 5000.

According to the [Netlify docs](https://github.com/netlify/cli/blob/b15f228d50afbf19dead2bf335198c055621fd8d/docs/netlify-dev.md), `targetPort` corresponds to the `The port for your application server, framework or site generator`.

Therefore, run `ntl dev` and make sure it has the `targetPort` configuration option set to 8080.

Comment: Great, this works :). The netlify CLI then opens the site on port 8888 (which can be changed if needed in the toml file, but it has to be different from the targetPort i.e. 8080). Also very nice that you shared the background information with us how that error came to be.

Comment: Awesome, glad things worked out!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue pretty easily. To know if you can hit the function directly on your desired port `8080`, you should look for the following to appear in your logs after running `ntl dev`:

```
   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                 │
   │   ◈ Server now ready on http://localhost:8080   │
   │                                                 │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

To get this to appear, I had to change a setting in the UI (it did not work to change it in `netlify.toml`). Go to `Site Settings -> Functions -> Functions Directory` and change the value from `functions` to `netlify/functions`. See the screenshot for what my settings page looked like after I made the change (red box mine):

[image]

I had this same issue when first running Svelte and Netlify functions together—I recall this resolving the issue for me then, too, but I can't find the forum/SO question that helped me find this out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this  does not work for me. And I also don't understand why it should help to change a folder since a) the issue is about a port, and b) the URL works in prod (just not in dev). The function server is still a random number. Also, the folder for my functions is "functions", not "netlify/functions". Should I change it as well?

Comment: Yes, try creating a `netlify/functions` directory in the root directory of your project. The function server will always be a random number, but there is an additional proxy server that starts up on port 8888 by default (8080 in your case) that will redirect requests to the function server.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Can you tell me how your complete folder structure looks like? The CLI also created a .netlify folder (notice the dot), but I assume the functions need to go in a separate folder (without dot)? What will be the request URL? Can you also tell me how your netlify.toml looks like? With this setup the request even does not work in prod. By the way I also don't get a message like "Server is now ready on". The svelte compiler (resp. rollup) logs: "Your application is ready~!   - Local: http://localhost:8080 - Network:  Add `--host` to expose". In any case I get 404.

Comment: Please see my other answer. I have arrived at a different conclusion that I think is markedly different than this.